# Problrm with redirect in Items Adding

Tags: development

I put in items adding this code:

```
SPUtility.Redirect("http://gzawistowskilap/SitePages/Event.aspx", SPRedirectFlags.Trusted, current);
```

If I try to add something a error shows:

The Ribbon Tab with id: "Ribbon.Read" has not been made available for this page or does not exist.
Use Ribbon.MakeTabAvailable().

**I Only wont to refresh site**

Here its screen of error:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grzegorz,

Your error is in the modal window where your form was. That's part of your problem. You aren't refreshing the parent page, you're refreshing the form page in the modal.

Why not scrap the refresh in the event receiver and create your own modal dialog handler?

Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8426773/how-to-refresh-a-parent-page-after-closing-sharepoint-dialog

Comment: I try ied this. At Item Adding when is Sinchronius is nothing happened, and if asynchronius is gneretea error: Error 4 Error occurred in deployment step 'Activate Features': Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
  0 0 Add4

Comment: Are you trying to load a wiki page in a modal window?

Comment: Web Part to web browser, not modal window. I'm trying reload site after adding

Comment: I've updated my answer. I think you're going about this the wrong way.

Comment: Test thanks, but how tu refresh the real site, not a popup. Meybe I don't understand something.

Comment: You need to write a callback handler for when the modal closes. You should get yourself a good book on web development in general and also one on SharePoint.